# how to pass my choice parameter value to ant in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

Hi Guys and thank you in advance, I am new two jenkins and I have a test automation project that i usually run it on different environment, now here is how my current project look like in jenkins
[image]

QA must to point to a specific configuration file example:
projectName/config/liveEnvironment.text

and the suites must point to the suite to be triggered:
projectName/suites/IAsuite.xml

and here is my ant command:

[image]

now what should the variable format look like in the ant, and how can it get it from the choice parameters.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters are set as environment variables.

In other words you should be able to call them with the normal syntax $variable_name

Comment: didn't get what you mean

Comment: As far as I understood your question you want to use the values from the choice parameters in jenkins in the ant command. This can be done by using $parameter_name.

Comment: Hi Wald, I want the QA value for example in the Environment drop down menu to represent a specific file directory, because i don't want the drop down values to be the entire directory, and also when referencing them in my ant command, what is the exact command must be, should it be something like "$QA " in my case or should it be $environment.QA ? thank you

Comment: It's a variable so using $Environment ( the name of your variable/choice parameter) is equivalent to having the chosen parameter written there.

The first is $Environment and the second is $suite